# Hibernating Rhinos - Entity Profiler - The type or namespace name 'Config' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity'

Tags: entity-framework-4

I installed Entity Profiler version 2.02145.0 by Hibernating Rhinos using Nu-Get.  It installed the required assemblies and created the following bootstrapper class:

```
 using HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework;


[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Application.Web.App_Start.EntityFrameworkProfilerBootstrapper), "PreStart")]
namespace Application.Web.App_Start
{
    public static class EntityFrameworkProfilerBootstrapper
    {
        public static void PreStart()
        {
            // Initialize the profiler
            EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize();

            // You can also use the profiler in an offline manner.
            // This will generate a file with a snapshot of all the EntityFramework activity in the application,
            // which you can use for later analysis by loading the file into the profiler.
            // var filename = @"c:\profiler-log";
            // EntityFrameworkProfiler.InitializeOfflineProfiling(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application I get this exception "The type or namespace name 'Config' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" on this line `EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize();`

System.Data.Entity is referenced in my web project.

Any ideas on how to resolve the error?

Comment: I wonder if this version is supposed to work against EF6 instead of EF4

Comment: just got the same error too any idea?

Comment: just got a different version and it is working with EF5 now

Comment: I emailed support, and they said it was a bug in build 2145 and to use 2144 or 2146. I can confirm that it work in 2146.